# Cannot ssh from Mac OS X to Linux

Tags: ssh

I have Linaro running in an embedded system (Zedboard). I am using the Mac Terminal to ssh to this system. The Zedboard has an IP. I set it in the interfaces file. This board is not connected to the internet and it is not running any firewall. I cannot ssh to this machine.

```
$ ssh -vvv root@169.254.218.146
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 169.254.218.146 [169.254.218.146] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 169.254.218.146 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 169.254.218.146 port 22: Connection refused
```

Shouldn't there be a debug3 for the third verbose? Ping works however. I can ping just fine and it responds. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: I noticed some strange behavior. My very first connection (after booting up Linaro) actually times out.

```
root@Vinayak’s MacBook Pro ~ $ ssh -vvv root@169.254.218.146
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 169.254.218.146 [169.254.218.146] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 169.254.218.146 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 169.254.218.146 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Any SUBSEQUENT ssh's give the connection refused result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the information displayed by the third debug level is relevant here. It displays additional details about the SSH connection, but no connection is being established at all here, so there's nothing to say.

Your output indicates that the Zedboard is not running an SSH server, or it is not configured to accept connections on this IP.

Comment: The operation timed out would limit it only to the later correct?

Comment: The "operation timed out" error looks like you tried to connect before networking came up on the board.

Comment: Our lab had an image of the kernel made and saved on our server. I downloaded that again and booted it up and it works fine. ssh some times does not work but ssh -vvv asks for RSA fingerprint authorization and then works. Either ways, the -vvv always works. I suppose I should find something about this. Thanks for your response though.